# How can i remove the hyperlink in jquery calendar

Tags: jquery, html, google-calendar-api

I am using jquery calendar used with Google calednar

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar

It shows the events but they have hyperlink which take the user to Google calendar page. is there any way that i only get the events name with or URL so that they should not be clickable

thanks

Comment: Nothing happens when I click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the documentation here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/

You will see that you just have to not set a URL in the object.

Comment: But URL will still be visible. i don't want to appear that in code

Comment: When you create the event you can avoid putting "url: www.something.com" so that you won't see the url and won't be able to click on the event.